# Why is the Targaryen coat of arms a three-headed dragon?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, why is the House Targaryen coat of arms/sigil a three-headed dragon?

Comment: Everything about the Targs is about 3 so probably that.

Comment: Please explane more i did not understand

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because of their close ties with dragons, and because the founder of the dynasty, Aegon Targaryen, achieved the historic conquest of the Seven Kingdoms which involved using **three dragons** being ridden by himself and his two sisters.

From *A Clash of Kings*, book 2 in George R. R. Martins novel series, *A Song of Ice and Fire*, that the show is based on:

> So many threes. Three fires, three mounts to ride, three treasons. “The dragon has three
>   heads,” she sighed. “Do you know what that means, Jorah?”
>   “Your Grace? The sigil of House Targaryen is a three-headed dragon, red on black.”
>   “I know that. But there are no three-headed dragons.”
>   “**The three heads were Aegon and his sisters**.”
>   “Visenya and Rhaenys,” she recalled. “I am descended from Aegon and Rhaenys through their son Aenys and their grandson
>   Jaehaerys.”
>   <sub>—*A Clash of Kings*, Chapter 63, Daenerys</sub>

In case you doubt Jorah's word, considering Martin's use of "unrealiable narrator", Martin makes this explicitly clear in the **Appendix** of the same book (*A Clash of Kings*):

> The banner of the Targaryens is the banner of Aegon the Conqueror, who conquered six of Seven Kingdoms, founded the
>   dynasty, and made the Iron Throne from the swords of his conquered enemies: a three-headed dragon, red on black.
>   <sub>—*A Clash of Kings*, Appendix, The Kings and their Courts: The Queen Across the Water</sub>

From the ["House Targaryen"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Targaryen) article on A Wiki of Ice and Fire:

> As one of the forty **dragonlord** families of Valyria, the **Targaryens were closer to dragons than other men**. Aenar Targaryen brought five dragons with him when he moved from Valyria to Dragonstone, and **Aegon I Targaryen and his sister-wives, Rhaenys and Visenya rode them to battle during the Conquest of the Seven Kingdoms** in 2 BC - 1 BC.
>   <sub>—"House Targaryen", A Wiki of Ice and Fire</sub>

also

> The three-headed dragon represents **the Conqueror and his two sisters**, Rhaenys and Visenya
>   <sub>—"House Targaryen", A Wiki of Ice and Fire</sub>

Comment: The symbolism of 3 goes further than this, they have 3 children etc. Or is that because of this initial event?

Comment: Who is `they` in your one example there, @TheLethalCoder? The banner was established by Aegon Targaryen the first, and the explicit reason we're given is that it represents the three dragons (figurative dragons (the Targaryen siblings, and literal dragons, the creatures they rode on) responsible for conquering and uniting the Seven Kingdoms to be ruled by their dynasty.

Comment: I asked `Or is that because of this initial event?` which your answer is yes. No need to be snarky about it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Hm, there was a legit miscommunication - I'll apologise upfront for this: I truly had no intention of snarkiness or malintent, I promise. I am lied down on my bed, very relaxed, and I always enjoy discussing GoT with you everywhere on this site (especially in comments) - I legit was wondering which 3 children you meant, and had no hidden intent of malice - I actually thought you may have been referring to Rhaegar's 3 kids, of Aerys' 3 kids, and I only wanted to know which you meant.

Comment: Fair enough may have misread your comment a bit. But I meant Rhaegars and some others, though I don't know the names as I'm not the best on the history.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thank goodness - I suppose my tone isn't always the warmest, but I promise it has nothing to do with an intent to be snarky or sarcastic or condescend people, it's just my natural internet/text tone, especially on Wiki-style, information/fact-based environments like this one. RE: `Rhaegars and some others` Well, the banner was made when Aegon founded the dynasty - it *does* represent 3 siblings/children of the same parents in the figurative "3 dragons" sense, too.

Comment: I suppose the symbolism of 3 for the Targs comes from this then too?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't know. I'm not very aware of this `symbolism of 3` that supposedly `goes further than this`. It may well be, but I am not aware of all the instances of 3 `for the Targs`, so I can't comment.

Comment: To be honest I only read it somewhere so can't say for certain either.

Comment: <In case you doubt Jorah's word, considering Martin's use of "unrealiable narrator", Martin makes this explicitly clear in the Appendix of the same book> but the words you highlight ("The three heads were Aegon and his sisters.") are nowhere in that Appendix passage, only in the wiki.

Comment: @Federico Maybe you missed `is the banner of Aegon the Conqueror`

Comment: @GhotiandChips no, I did not miss that. The fact that is the banner of Aegon is not being said by Jorah. And the fact that it is his banner does not imply that "The three heads were Aegon and his sisters" those statements are not equivalent.

Comment: @Federico You're free to believe that. I can read Jorah talking about the sigil and Aegon, but you're totally free to ignore it. I don't mind/care.